# Почему не отправляет данные повторно?

Tags: ajax, javascript, form

**UPD:** Раз здесь некоторые не понимают простого текста, я напишу еще проще.

Есть форма, есть ajax запрос на отправку данных с формы. При в воде данных ajax отправляет их в php обработчик, там производится валидация, и результаты валидации возвращаются в виде json.

Если введенные данные пользователем не прошли валидацию, пользователь их устраняет и нажимает повторно submit, я вывожу ошибки и крашу форму в красный цвет вот таким методом:

```
if(response.fail) {
  $.each(response.errors, function( index, value ) {
      $('#'+index+'_error').empty().append(value);
      $('#'+index).parent().addClass('form-group');
      $('#'+index+'_err').addClass('form-group has-error');
  });
}
```

Далее пользователь устраняет ошибки и повторно нажимает submit, форма вроде как и отправляется, но ошибки валидации данных так и остались, несмотря на то, что форма 100% должна была пройти валидацию.

В чем может быть причина подобного поведения? Я думаю, теперь суть ясна на все 100%.

Ajax:

```
$('#signup').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('input[type=submit]').prop({
            disabled: true,
            value:"Подождите..."
        });
        $('input[type=submit]').blur();

        var username = $('#username').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var confirm = $('#confirm').val();
        var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{ URL::action('AuthController@signup') }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                _token:_token,
                username:username,
                email:email,
                password:password,
                confirm:confirm
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('input[type=submit]').prop({
                    disabled: false,
                    value:"Сосдать аккаунт"
                });
                if(response.fail) {
                    $.each(response.errors, function( index, value ) {
                        $('#'+index+'_error').empty().append(value);
                        $('#'+index).parent().addClass('form-group');
                        $('#'+index+'_err').addClass('form-group has-error');
                    });
                }
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: А что отладка показывает? На сервере повторная валидация действительно проходит успешно, то есть ошибка именно на UI? Мне кажется, методом пристального дебага эту ошибку отловить не трудно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, что значит "*и отправляю форму повторно*"? Вы отправляете форму программно или предлагаете повторить запрос  пользователю?

> исправляю ошибки

Долго чесал затылок, но так и не въехал, как вы можете находить ошибки в заполняемых пользователем данных, да еще и исправлять их?

> ошибки отображаются как и прежде

Даже если вы умудряетесь проводить "работу над ошибками", то где вы изменяете значение полей, после "правки"? Я лишь наблюдаю некий вывод предупреждений или что-то в этом роде.

**Обновление**

Как бы вам ни хотелось, но бреда в моих словах нет ни грамма, а если вы перечитаете свой вопрос, то увидите его там гораздо больше. Ошибки и несоответствие установленному вами формату (*если вы это имели в виду*) - вещи абсолютно разные. Соответствие или несоответствие формату проверяется еще на клиенте, а не гоняется паровозами на сервер и обратно. Если же под ошибками и прочим, вы  имели в виду что-то другое, то изъясняйтесь понятно, иначе ваш бред будет порождать другой.

**Обновление 2**

В том коде, который показали вы, я проблем не наблюдаю. Единственное, что вызывает подозрение - это "**токен**". Если вы его генерируете динамически при каждом обращении на сервер, то проблема может быть в нём. В форме осталось старое значение, а после неудачного запроса на сервер, генерируется и записывается в сессию или печеньки уже новое. В общем, для начала проверьте в этом направлении.

Comment: @Deonis обновил вопрос, чтобы вы смогли понять.

Comment: @Bastian, Обновил ответ